# Android biometrics UserNotAuthenticatedException on fingerprint

Tags: java, android, exception, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

I'm using a SecretKey in my sample app for Mac-signing. The key is generated with builder parameter

```
setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10)
```

to allow the usage of the fingerprint **and** the (un)lock device PIN to secure my key.

The UI does only contain a SIGN button to start the signature.

If I'm using the biometric prompt via "Use PIN", after input of the PIN I receive the signature
(in my example "2BjEuSxl/bOTTUExE4vTX2rnRZEC1Zfa21FooKkBfnc=") [note: expected behaviour].

Pressing the SIGN-button again within the given 10 seconds "ValidityDuration" period I can use the fingerprint for authorization successfully [note: expected behaviour].

Pressing the SIGN button after 10 seconds and using the fingerprint for authorization
[or use the fingerprint without prior usage of the PIN] gives an exception [note: **not** expected behaviour]:

```
android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated
```

**So my question is: how can I use the *same* SecretKey to authorize the sign process (or better the release of the key from AndroidKeystore) with the PIN and fingerprint option ?**

I'm testing on Android SDK 30 (target) and (minimum) 23, the biometric functions are available with implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0'.

Below is the Logcat debug-output with some comments from my side:

```
>>> first start
2021-07-04 14:23:47.178 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: sign started
2021-07-04 14:23:47.181 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: try to load secretKey from keystore
2021-07-04 14:23:47.211 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: generated fresh key, try to load
2021-07-04 14:23:47.223 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: UserNotAuthenticatedException thrown, try to authenticate

>>> biometric prompt, used the PIN [authType = 1]:
2021-07-04 14:24:04.089 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: Authentication succeeded with authType 1
2021-07-04 14:24:04.089 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: (authType: 1=PIN, 2=fingerprint)
2021-07-04 14:24:04.092 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: try to load secretKey from keystore
2021-07-04 14:24:04.097 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/signed data: a1wbBdybQkP30XWFBj0o8fiVrS8BXlREGmDHQQQhEwg=

>>> pressed "SIGN" again after 5 seconds
2021-07-04 14:24:09.725 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: sign started
2021-07-04 14:24:09.730 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: try to load secretKey from keystore
2021-07-04 14:24:13.421 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: Authentication succeeded with authType 2
2021-07-04 14:24:13.422 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: (authType: 1=PIN, 2=fingerprint)
2021-07-04 14:24:13.426 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: try to load secretKey from keystore
2021-07-04 14:24:13.432 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/signed data: a1wbBdybQkP30XWFBj0o8fiVrS8BXlREGmDHQQQhEwg=

>>> pressed "SIGN" again 21 seconds after the PIN authorization
2021-07-04 14:24:23.348 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: sign started
2021-07-04 14:24:23.359 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: try to load secretKey from keystore
2021-07-04 14:24:23.366 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: UserNotAuthenticatedException thrown, try to authenticate
>>> fingerprint is accepted [authType = 2]
2021-07-04 14:24:25.356 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: Authentication succeeded with authType 2
2021-07-04 14:24:25.356 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: (authType: 1=PIN, 2=fingerprint)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.361 6980-6980/de.biometrics D/*** Biometric ***: try to load secretKey from keystore
>>> the exception is thrown on line 86:
>>> mac.init(getOrCreateSecretKey(KEY_NAME_SIGN));
2021-07-04 14:24:25.377 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err: android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated
2021-07-04 14:24:25.377 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1346)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.378 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1388)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.379 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.379 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreHmacSpi.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreHmacSpi.java:184)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.380 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreHmacSpi.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreHmacSpi.java:101)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.380 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Mac.chooseProvider(Mac.java:443)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.380 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Mac.init(Mac.java:513)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.380 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at de.biometrics.MainActivity$1.onAuthenticationSucceeded(MainActivity.java:86)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.381 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at androidx.biometric.BiometricFragment$9.run(BiometricFragment.java:907)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.381 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.381 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.382 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.384 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.385 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.386 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
2021-07-04 14:24:25.386 6980-6980/de.biometrics W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

This is the complete source code (MainActivity.java):

**Edit:** I slightly changed the createKey-function to be more compliant with the documentation on https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#java

```
package de.biometrics;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // use dependency in build.graddle:
    // implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0'

    private static final String KEY_NAME_SIGN = "SignKey";
    private static final int VALIDITY_DURATION_SECONDS = 10;
    private static final String APP_TAG = "*** Biometric *** ";

    private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
    private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;
    private Executor executor;
    Button btnSign;
    Mac mac;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
        btnSign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        // Allows user to authenticate using either a Class 3 biometric or
        // their lock screen credential (PIN, pattern, or password).
        promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
                .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
                // Can't call setNegativeButtonText() and
                // setAllowedAuthenticators(...|DEVICE_CREDENTIAL) at the same time.
                // .setNegativeButtonText("Use account password")
                .setAllowedAuthenticators(
                        androidx.biometric.BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG
                                | androidx.biometric.BiometricManager.Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
                .build();

        biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(MainActivity.this,
                executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                              @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "Authentication succeeded!");
            }
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                    @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                int authorizationType = result.getAuthenticationType();
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "Authentication succeeded with authType " + authorizationType);
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "(authType: 1=PIN, 2=fingerprint)");
                try {
                    // init mac from scratch
                    mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
                    mac.init(getOrCreateSecretKey(KEY_NAME_SIGN));
                    byte[] bytes = "secret-text".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    byte[] macResult = mac.doFinal(bytes);
                    Log.d("signed data ", Base64.encodeToString(macResult, Base64.NO_WRAP));
                } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "Authentication failed");
            }
        });

        btnSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sign();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sign() {
        // simple sign function
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "sign started");
        // setup the mac
        try {
            mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(getOrCreateSecretKey(KEY_NAME_SIGN));
        } catch (UserNotAuthenticatedException e) {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "UserNotAuthenticatedException thrown, try to authenticate");
            biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
    }

    private SecretKey getOrCreateSecretKey(String keyName) {
        SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey(keyName);
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "try to load secretKey from keystore");
        if (secretKey == null) {
            createSecretKey(keyName);
            secretKey = getSecretKey(keyName);
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "generated fresh key, try to load");
        }
        return secretKey;
    }

    private SecretKey getSecretKey(String keyName) {
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            // Before the keystore can be accessed, it must be loaded.
            keyStore.load(null);
            return ((SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(keyName, null));
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

private void createSecretKey(String keyName) {
        generateSecretKey(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                keyName,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                //.setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10)
                .build());
    }// All exceptions unhandled

    private void generateSecretKey(KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec) {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = null;
        try {
            keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA256, "AndroidKeyStore");
            keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
            keyGenerator.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Sign"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

build.graddle (Module):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.biometrics"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0'
}
```

Note: this is just a very simplified program, just for testing the biometric prompt functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, as my findings maybe helpful to others.

Up to now (July 6th 2021) I do have no idea why a SecretKey that is generated with the option

```
.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10);
```

cannot get **released** by fingerprint first. As written in my question, when it's released first by PIN (device credential) it could get **used** ("authenticated") by fingerprint as long the duration period is not expired.

Anyway, there is another option available in the docs **Authenticate using auth-per-use keys**
(https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#auth-per-use-keys) and this option
gives the expected result.

Don't forget to **generate a fresh key** when updating your code with the new code!

When using the new option

```
.setUserAuthenticationParameters(0 /* duration */,
   KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG |
   KeyProperties.AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
```

you will notice that the code requires SDK 30+ to run. For code that runs on SDK > 23 you can use

```
.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(0)
```

It's important to use "0" seconds as this (internally) defaults to "BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL",
when using "-1" it defaults to "DEVICE_CREDENTIAL" (without the fingerprint option).

Below I'm providing code that checks for the SDK in use and chooses the correct generateKey-function:

```
private SecretKey getOrCreateSecretKey(String keyName) {
    SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey(keyName);
    Log.d(APP_TAG, "try to load secretKey from keystore");
    if (secretKey == null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            createSecretKeyApi2329(keyName);
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "createSecretKeyApi2329 SDK in use:  " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            createSecretKeyApi30(keyName);
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "createSecretKeyApi30 SDK in use:  " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        }
        // as minimum SDK in build.gradle was set to 23 the version can't be below 23
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "SDK in use is to old, minimum SDK is 23 = M");
            finish();
        }
        secretKey = getSecretKey(keyName);
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "generated fresh key, try to load");
    }
    return secretKey;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
private void createSecretKeyApi30(String keyName) {
    generateSecretKey(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            keyName,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
            //.setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
            // Accept either a biometric credential or a device credential.
            // To accept only one type of credential, include only that type as the
            // second argument.
            // @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            .setUserAuthenticationParameters(0 /* duration */,
                    KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG |
                            KeyProperties.AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
            .build());
}// All exceptions unhandled

//@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void createSecretKeyApi2329(String keyName) {
    generateSecretKey(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            keyName,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
            //.setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
            // Accept either a biometric credential or a device credential.
            // To accept only one type of credential, include only that type as the
            // second argument.
            // for SDK < 30 use .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(0)
            // see https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r3:frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.java;l=1236-1246;drc=a811787a9642e6a9e563f2b7dfb15b5ae27ebe98
            // parameter "0" defaults to AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG | AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL
            // parameter "-1" default to AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG
            .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(0)
            .build());
}// All exceptions unhandled
```

Comment: Thank you so much on following up on this!  Was super helpful for me today.

Comment: `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(-1)` defaults to `AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG`